# execute function in created and inserted DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

My intention is very simple: I have a `newSpan()` function, that creates a new `span` and inserts it before the first child of the `main` element (or appends it if `main` is empty), and a `letterTyper()` function, that fills the inserted element with the string stored in a `CONTENT` constant while generating a sort of backwards typing effect. The idea is to create a new element and then triggering the effect inside it a given number of times with a loop in `window.onload`.

But when I fill the `window.onload` anonymous function with

```
window.onload = function() {
  newSpan();
  letterTyper();
  newSpan();
  letterTyper();
}
```

What I end up with in the DOM is

```
<main>
  <span id="#span1">lorem ipsum</span>
  <span id="#span0"></span>
</main>
```

I also tried to use a `DOMContentLoaded` event, to no effect. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
const CONTENT = 'lorem ipsum';
var main = document.querySelector('main');
var spanId = 0;
var charCount = CONTENT.length;


window.onload = function() {
  newSpan();
  letterTyper();
  newSpan();
  letterTyper();
}

function newSpan() {
  var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  var isEmpty = main.innerHTML === '';

  newSpan.setAttribute('id', '#span' + spanId);

  if (isEmpty) {
    main.appendChild(newSpan);
  } else {
    main.insertBefore(newSpan, document.getElementById('#span' + (spanId - 1)));
  }

  spanId++;
}

function letterTyper() {
  var targetSpan = main.firstChild;
  targetSpan.textContent = CONTENT.substring(charCount, charCount + 1) + targetSpan.textContent.substring(0, targetSpan.textContent.length);
  charCount--;

  if ( charCount < 0) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      charCount = CONTENT.length;
  } else {
      timer = setTimeout('letterTyper()', 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: window.onload executes only once, also don't place any loops there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous. When you call `letterTyper` for the first time, it will return to your `window.onload` and trigger the next `newSpan()` and `letterTyper()`.

That means that the `letterTyper` loop of the first span interferes with the second loop, because the first loop hasn't finished when the second one is started. In other words, the second loop is never created, but all calls of `letterTyper` will see the `#span1` element (the second span element) as the first child of `main`.

You have to wait until the first loop is finished before you start the second loop. I suggest you take a look at [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

I changed a few things in your code so that is now uses promises:

```js
const CONTENT = 'lorem ipsum';
var main = document.querySelector('main');
var spanId = 0;
var charCount = CONTENT.length;

window.onload = function() {
  // start the first loop
  letterTyper(newSpan()).then(function () {
    // the first loop has finished, start the second loop
    return letterTyper(newSpan());
  }).then(function () {
    // the second loop has finished, start the third loop
    return letterTyper(newSpan());
  });
}

function newSpan() {
  var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
  var isEmpty = main.children.length === 0;

  newSpan.setAttribute('id', '#span' + spanId);

  if (isEmpty) {
    main.appendChild(newSpan);
  } else {
    main.insertBefore(newSpan, document.getElementById('#span' + (spanId - 1)));
  }

  spanId++;
  charCount = CONTENT.length; // reset the character count
  
  return newSpan;
}

function letterTyper(span) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // executes one tick (adds one character and calls itself after 100ms)
    var tick = function () {
      // prepend a new character
      span.textContent = CONTENT[charCount -= 1] + span.textContent;
      if (charCount > 0) {
        // call tick again in 100ms
        setTimeout(tick, 100);
      } else {
        // loop is finished, the "then" part will be called
        resolve();
      }
    };
    // start the loop 
    setTimeout(tick, 100);
  });
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```